# Join in play2 framework with JPA EntityManager - ResultSet as Map?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I did not find a solution for this simple question:

**How to join two tables in play2 framework without creating a result class?**

```
EntityManager em = JPA.em();
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a.name, b.birthday FROM TABLE a JOIN TABLE b");
List<Object> l = q.getResultList();
```

the json mapper maps this *without fieldnames* to:

```
[ {"name", "12/10/2016"}, {..} ]
```

How do I get the most easy way:

```
[{ name:"name", birthday:"12/10/2016"}, {...} ]
```

Maybe there is a mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mean time I found this solution, which only requires the field names in the right order:

```
String[] fields = {"id","name","birthday","email"};
return resultToHashmap(q.getResultList(), fields);
```

And the 'magic' function, which manually transform the result to a Hashmap of .

```
  private static List<Map<String, Object>> resultToHashmap(List<Object[]> resultList, String[] fieldNames ){

        List<Map<String, Object>> resultMap  = new ArrayList();
        for (Object[] result : resultList){
            HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>(result.length);
            for (int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                row.put(fieldNames[i],result[i]);
            }
            resultMap.add(row);
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
```